# Disable Ubuntu 20.04 disk checkup every boot?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 20.04, persistence

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 persistent on my usb. Every time boot, it starts disk checkup. I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> every time. I want to disable it permanently. And also for each shutdown it says press enter to remove installation medium.

Comment: There have been quite a few complaints about the disk check in Ask Ubuntu so far. I have not yet seen an answer except to do a Full install of Ubuntu to USB instead of Persistent. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step . Another irritating bug is the Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu screen has reappeared in persistent installs. mkusb should have a fix soon. It is possible to fix in Rufus by overwriting syslinux.cfg.

Comment: Bug report including disk check: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1863672

Comment: New Bug Report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1875548

Comment: Thank you, for that.

Comment: The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Removing Disk Check on Persistent USB's

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` will still come up but **fsck** will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

Edit the boot files below booted from a desktop or Live USB, not booted from the new persistent drive.

**mkusb** After the Persistent USB drive is created, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Persistent menuentry thus:

  ```
  linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip quiet splash persistent ---
  ```
- **Newer versions of mkusb already include this fix**.
- If you also wish to remove the **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen delete "maybe-ubiquity".

**UNetbootin** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the first menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open syslinux.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the default menuentry for (BIOS boot mode).

**Rufus** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Default menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open /isolinux/txt.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the "Try Ubuntu without installing" menuentry, (for BIOS boot mode).

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from BIOS boot by overwriting syslinux.cfg with:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting an Ubuntu Persistent session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt --
```

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from Rufus UEFI boot by removing "maybe-ubiquity" from /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

**Edit 20200524:**
The above workaround is no longer needed.

This bug was fixed in the package casper - 1.447, as announced in:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y casper
```

I am still testing the fix.

Comment: Thanks to brian-murray for fsck.mode=skip

Comment: Cannot find grub.cfg in /boot/grub/ . I used Rufus for installing persistent.

Comment: @Tylore: I am running Rufus-3.10 with persistence and all default settings. If you are running the USB, /boot/grub/grub.cfg will be in /cdrom/ but that will be read only. To modify grub.cfg edit from Windows or another Live USB.

Comment: @Tylore: I have edited the answer, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @muru: Thank you for the edit but. **Please explain why you say "it was just poorly formatted"** and how adding a few spaces fixed it. I understand that the latest ISO uses multi space tabs where you show multiple spaces, however every example of a GRUB menuentry I can find on the Internet, including Official Ubuntu Documentation, shows single spaces in these locations, the same as I showed. I have been testing all morning and can find no advantage to adding spaces.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15582/158442

Comment: @muru: your example is about indenting, which is spaces at the beginning of the line **not between words**. If you are following the example you should put eight spaces in front of "linux" in your edit. Please explain why single space between words is poor formatting.

Comment: @muru My apologies, I see that there was a problem with code highlighting on that piece of code. The indents should be right but sometimes my code button does not work. I thought you did not like my single space between words.