# Installation stuck at checking disks 20%

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside windows 10 and using unetbootin. When i boot on the unetbootin and choose install ubuntu the screen gets stuck on checking disks: 20% complete while checking the file ./pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_i386.deb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Filesystem Check

At about 20% through the file check, Boot starts checking the file filesystem.squashfs, which takes up about 90% of the ISO and contains most of the OS files. This may take awhile. You can either give it time or remove filesystem checking See: [Disable Ubuntu 20.04 disk checkup every boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231734/disable-ubuntu-20-04-disk-checkup-every-boot/1232719#1232719)

If you press the ESC key you should see what is happening behind the splash screen.

If the persistence file/partition is full it may not proceed beyond this point until all files in casper-rw are deleted.

Comment: I can confirm this. The progress bar might seem stalled at 19-20%, but once it resumes, it goes very quickly again. The filesystem check just takes a long time.