# Disc check each time I boot to a USB to Try Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: live-usb

First time this ever happened with a Ubuntu release, I get a disc check each time I boot to a USB drive to Try Ubuntu 20.04.

Is because of the way the USB drive is formatted (NTSC) or the tool I used to create the bootable USB drive (Universal-USB-Installer)?

Or is there something I can change in Ubuntu 20.04 to stop this?

Comment: That's a new feature to prevent people from installing from a corrupted USB. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: ...except the clear instructions written on the screen *during* the check.

Comment: @mook765 See my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Ubuntu 20.04 disk checkup every boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231734/disable-ubuntu-20-04-disk-checkup-every-boot)

Answer (score 1):

### Removing Disk Check on Persistent USB's

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` will still come up but **fsck** will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

**mkusb** After the Persistent USB drive is created, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Persistent menuentry thus:

`linux  ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip quiet splash persistent ---`

- **Newer versions of mkusb already include this fix**
- If you also wish to remove the **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen delete "maybe-ubiquity".

**UNetbootin** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the first menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open syslinux.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the default menuentry for (BIOS boot mode).

**Rufus** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Default menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open /isolinux/txt.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the "Try Ubuntu without installing" menuentry, (for BIOS boot mode).

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from BIOS boot by overwriting syslinux.cfg with:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting an Ubuntu Persistent session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt --
```

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from Rufus UEFI boot by removing "maybe-ubiquity" from /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

**Edit 20200524:**
The above workaround is no longer needed.

This bug was fixed in the package casper - 1.447, as announced in:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y casper
```

I am still testing this fix.