# Increasing performance of USB live boot - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 20.04, live-usb

I have created Ubuntu 20.04 LTS live USB. However the booting time is very dissatisfactory. It takes almost 10-15 minutes to boot.

I used an 8 giga bytes capacity USB and kept 3 giga bytes of persistence storage. Keeping persistence effect the performance of live usb? Or is it because my pc has only 4 giga bytes of RAM? I want to know about the general factors affecting performance and speed of live usb boot.

Please give any suggestions to improve the performance of live USB.

Comment: Use a hard drive or much better, an SSD if you want fast boot times.

Comment: Performance is hardware dependent. The USB 3.1 SSD in the form factor of a thumb drive has much better performance than a regular USB flash drive.

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre) and links from it about the speed of USB pendrives. But it is a good idea to use an SSD (connected via a USB 3 adapter). Nowadays a SATA SSD plus a USB 3 to SATA adapter are cheaper and faster compared to the fastest USB 3.x pendrives, at least after using the drive for some time.

Comment: Disk check can take a while, to stop  it see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231734/disable-ubuntu-20-04-disk-checkup-every-boot

Comment: I can confirm this also happens with me with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop image, release version. I use a Team C171 USB 2.0 16GB flash disk. I don't enable persistence. I tested on my Lenovo ThinkPad 13 (20GJ) with 16GB RAM and my custom-built PC with 32GB RAM. Both computers need at least 5 minutes to show the "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" dialog