# Excessive slowness booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop Live USB

Tags: live-usb, 22.04, wayland, ubiquity, usb-creator

For some reason, the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop `amd64` image takes ~5 minutes to boot on both my laptop and my workstation. I downloaded the image using the [official torrent](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) so it's automatically verified. I created the live USB using Ubuntu's "Startup Disk Creator" (`usb-creator-gtk`) system tool. The flash disk is a Team C171 16 GB USB 2.0 flash disk and is a dedicated installer stick.

My laptop is a [Lenovo ThinkPad 13 (20GJ)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-13-series-laptop/thinkpad-13/20gj/20gjcto1ww/lr070sa0) with the following specs:

- Intel Core i5-6300U ("Haswell")
- 16 GB DDR4-2133 RAM (2x 8 GB Lenovo OEM RMSA3230KB78HAF2133)
- 1 TB Corsair MX500 M.2 SATA SSD
- Currently dual-booting Windows 10 Home and Ubuntu Linux 20.04.4 LTS Desktop with rEFInd boot manager.

My [custom-built workstation "BaseCamp"](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/wileamyp/saved/vCc34D) has the following specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600X ("Matisse"/"Zen 2")
- 32 GB DDR4-3200 RAM (2x 16 GB OLOy MD4U163216CFDA)
- 256 GB Patriot P300 M.2 NVMe SSD
- 2x 3 TB Seagate Constellation ES.3 3.5" 7200 RPM HDD (running AMD RAID)
- AMD Radeon HD6570 1GB (HP OEM)
- Currently booting Ubuntu Linux 20.04.4 LTS Desktop with rEFInd boot manager.

Also, ubiquity crashes on BaseCamp. I submitted the crash report using the `apport` dialog. Potato quality picture here: [image: potato_quality_picture]

As suggested by @user535733 in the comments, `systemd-analyze critical-chain` looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~# systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @9min 59.900s
└─multi-user.target @9min 59.900s
  └─casper-md5check.service @44.452s +9min 15.447s
    └─basic.target @44.448s
      └─sockets.target @44.448s
        └─snapd.socket @44.448s +519us
          └─sysinit.target @44.444s
            └─snapd.apparmor.service @38.751s +5.693s
              └─systemd-journald.socket @5.116s
                └─system.slice @5.113s
                  └─-.slice @5.113s
```

And here's the output of `systemctl status ubiquity`:

```
× ubiquity.service - Ubuntu live CD installer
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ubiquity.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-04-26 16:36:07 UTC; 16min ago
    Process: 1731 ExecStart=/usr/share/ubiquity/start-ubiquity-dm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1731 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 2.729s

Apr 26 16:32:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu live CD installer...
Apr 26 16:35:24 ubuntu python3[1752]: PAM pam_end: NULL pam handle passed
Apr 26 16:35:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: ubiquity.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 26 16:36:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: ubiquity.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 26 16:36:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer.
Apr 26 16:36:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: ubiquity.service: Consumed 2.729s CPU time.
```

This might be related: [Increasing performance of USB live boot - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301375/increasing-performance-of-usb-live-boot-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

It's a shame the 22.04 LTS boot screen no longer shows the progress bar of verifying the installer, unlike 20.04 LTS.

PS: I consider myself a power user, hence the highly customized setup on both my laptop and workstation. I've been using Ubuntu for ~10 years now, both desktop and server, so definitely not a noob. I'm willing to contribute towards fixing this in ubiquity.

Update: I'm starting to think the ubiquity crash is Wayland-related since BaseCamp also crashes with a black screen on 20.04 LTS. I install `gnome-session-wayland`, reboot, then pick "Ubuntu on Wayland" session at the login screen, login, and poof everything turns black. Fortunately I can SSH from my laptop to it to issue a `sudo reboot`.

Comment: if both machines are taking excessive time to boot, don't reckon it is related to hardware. Were there any customized selection(s) you chose during installation?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon I haven't started the installation process yet. The slowness is during the boot phase. For the "BaseCamp" workstation I can't even start the installation process because ubiquity crashes.

Comment: To be precise, the slowness is between choosing to boot the Grub EFI binary from the flashdisk and when ubiquity prompts language selection and "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu"

Comment: The LiveUSB, once booted, has troubleshooting tools available: What do the logs say? What does `systemd-analyze critical-chain` say?

Comment: @user535733 I'm accessing this post on my laptop, so lemme test `systemd-analyze critical-chain` on BaseCamp. Will post another comment with a pastebin link soon. Which logs should I upload?

Comment: We don't want to read your logs, so don't upload them. Review your logs looking for errors, warnings, time-gaps, and other suspicious items.

Comment: I do want to forward the logs to the ubiquity devs though, so they can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Naive question: Looking at the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is it not the case that almost 9 mins of your boot is due to disc checking? If that is the case, is it possible to disable that part of the boot? -- [Disable Ubuntu 20.04 disk checkup every boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231734/disable-ubuntu-20-04-disk-checkup-every-boot)

Another solution could be testing the speed on your USB stick and trying to see how it matches up to others, especially if upgrading to 3.0 is a possibility.

Comment: That is correct, 9 minutes of disk checking. The solution you linked to disable it seems to require persistence mode? I might buy a USB 3.0 stick once I see it on sale.